# Tackling challenging semi-weekly or weekly data with gaps

Tags: unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am working on ferry itineraries (i.e. tickets sold in a specific itinerary). Consider the scenarios:

1) itinerary taken only on Tuesdays and Thursdays every week ( but with gaps - depending on weather)
2) itinerary taken daily but only during 4 months a year (from June to September and again next June etc).
How do you declare such series as ts in R? For example, in scenario (1) will it work if I set frequency=2*52?
And how does R tackle the gaps (i.e. cancelled trips due to bad weather causing missing Tuesdays or Thursdays?)
any feedback would be mostly appreciated. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your time series doesn’t need to be on a conventional schedule, like seven days a week or 12 months a year, in order to be considered evenly spaced. As you already suggested you just need to set the frequency according to the ferry schedule for both. 
Update: You will need to make it a `msts` object not `ts` in order to specify multiple seasonal frequencies (both # of weeks in the year/season and number of ferry days in the week).

For the canceled trips you should put either the number of tickets sold in advance of the cancellation or zero but utilize some kind of regressor to indicate the event (a column that is 1 when cancelled, 0 when not). That data is not truly missing, there’s just a a different kind of outcome.

Comment: It doesn't need to be on a "conventional schedule" but it does need to actually be *evenly* spaced: the distance between a Tuesday and the next data point (2 days) is not the same as to the previous data point (5 days). Considering that the data is heavily affected by the weather, I would expect Thursdays to show larger lag 1 autocorrelation than Tuesdays (whose "lag 1" is actually more than twice as far in time). Those things would need to be accounted for.

Comment: Wouldn’t that only be the case if you’re not using a seasonal parameter? I would say that the lag for both days is going back to the previous week. I’ll grant the point about the weather but the day of week seasonality plus week of year seasonality is quite likely to handle most of the autocorrelation. Editing my answer to make it explicit that it needs to be specified as msts.

Comment: Thank you both! @ChrisUmphlett you point that "For the canceled trips you should put either the number of tickets sold in advance...". Good point but as Chris Haug mentioned, "data are heavily affected by weather" so those passengers probably took the next scheduled trip. So do you think it would be better to give a value of zero and adding a dichotomous variable?

Comment: Are you forecasting tickets or riders? If tickets you may want to use the #; if riders yes it would be zero